# Load zip file from url with asyncio and aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, zip, python-asyncio, aiohttp

How can I load Zip file with GET request?

I use asyncio and aiohttp in my Python app. 
That's my code:

```
async def fetch_page(session, url):
    with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            assert response.status == 200
            return await response.read()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
links = ['http://www2.census.gov/census_2010/04-Summary_File_1/Louisiana/la2010.sf1.zip']
for link in links:
    with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        response = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_page(session, url=link))
        print(type(response))
```

And then I get asyncio.TimeoutError

Comment: If the file is large, it may take more than 10 seconds to download. Increase the timeout value you use or use None.

Comment: Also if you're downloading multiple files in parallel, your bandwidth will naturally be divided by the number of simultaneous downloads, so it'll multiply the download time by the same value. You'll easily hit the 10s per file if you're downloading 100s of files.